# WPF TextBox doesn`t update binded source

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-style

I've got a textbox with custom style and binded to it property. If i change value in textbox property doesn't changes but if property changed from code textbox updates right.
I guess it's Mode=TwoWay missing somewhere but I can't figure out where as if I clear style frm xaml it works fine.
Form xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbFrames" Height="27" Canvas.Left="53" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=frames, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Canvas.Top="185" Width="64" Style="{DynamicResource StyleTextBox}" PreviewTextInput="AnimationValidationTextBox"/>
```

Style xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="27" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border
                        x:Name="PART_border"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        BorderBrush="#FF434346"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        />
                    <TextBox Foreground="#FFBABAC7" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_border" Property="Background" Value="#FF414146" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF5A5A5D" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

And looks like working as like I`ve said before if I remove my style from control source updetes.
At first in style textbox binding was:

```
<TextBox Foreground="#FFBABAC7" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

And it doesn't worked so I've changed it to RelativeSource and TwoWay mode but there are still no result.
What can be wrong?

PreviewTextInputCode is :

```
private void AnimationValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    if (!animationOpened)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }

    NumberValidationTextBox(sender, e);
}

private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
    e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```

And property declared as:

```
   private int _frames;
    public int frames
    {
        get => _frames;
        set
        {
            _frames = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("frames");
        }
    }
```

And with default style frames updates both way with all this checking.

Comment: Could you post the event handler code for PreviewTextInput? I've tested your example and it worked as expected. Only difference is, that I've deleted the PreviewTextInput.

Comment: @Ben Yes, I`ll add it to question

Comment: It's working as long as `animationOpened` is true. I can enter numbers in the TextBox and manipulate the Property from code (by button) and the manipulation is shown in the TextBox

Comment: @Ben, changing property value from code works well. It's shown in TextBox without problems. Entering text to be enabled only when `animationOpened` done for special purposes and it works. But when I enter new number in TextBox (not from code, `animationOpened=true`) value of `frames` do not changes. But if I remove `Style="{DynamicResource StyleTextBox}"` from xaml all works fine and value of `frames` changes through TextBox on Form. And I can't get why...

Comment: Strange, I can change the value of the property through the view without any problems. Could you add a simplified running example?

Comment: @Ben Yes it`s strange. When building simplifilied example with only one TextBox of that style and one button to watch debug results it's changing corresponding value both ways... Still I don't get it. If there was a problem inside code, just removing style from TextBox  wouldn't help but it does... As you see inside style declaration there are no dependencies to other elements. So I guess it's not a code problem. It's IDK what's happening...